# Is there any Problem in my Flutter (dart) code ? 'Local html is not showing in UI'

Tags: flutter, webview

I am Using this library (https://github.com/pedromassango/flutter_delivery) for drawer.
and i want to show Local html content in the home (Container) Widget,and i have followed this Webview Tutorial (http://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/05/25/load-local-html-file-into-webview-in-flutter-call-js-function-from-flutter/)

But nothing Worked for me !
Thanks in Advance !

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/05/25/load-local-html-file-into-webview-in-flutter-call-js-function-from-flutter/

main.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:delivery/circular_image.dart';
import 'package:delivery/menu_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:delivery/zoom_scaffold.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
String filePath = '/assests/files/abc1.html';
WebViewController _webViewController;
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new MaterialApp(

      title: 'Zoom Menu',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  MenuController menuController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    menuController = new MenuController(
      vsync: this,
    )..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    menuController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (context) => menuController,
      child: ZoomScaffold(
        menuScreen: MenuScreen(),
        contentScreen: Layout(

            contentBuilder: (cc) => Container(
                  color: Colors.grey[600],
                    child: WebView(
                      initialUrl: filePath,
                      javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                      onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                        _webViewController = webViewController;
                        _loadHtmlFromAssets();
                      },
                    ),

                )),
      ),
    );
  }
  _loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
    String fileHtmlContents = await rootBundle.loadString(filePath);
    _webViewController.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileHtmlContents,
        mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
        .toString());
  }
}



pubspec.taml

name: delivery
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.14+1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  provider: ^2.0.0
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assests/files/
    - assests/files/abc1.html
```

# I want to show the local html file content but showing nothing !

# but works with widget like Text color,etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 change /assets/files/abc1.html to assets/files/abc1.html , remove the frist / 
Step 2 initialUrl: ''

full code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:delivery/circular_image.dart';
import 'package:delivery/menu_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:delivery/zoom_scaffold.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
String filePath = 'assets/sample.html';
WebViewController _webViewController;
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new MaterialApp(

      title: 'Zoom Menu',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  MenuController menuController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    menuController = new MenuController(
      vsync: this,
    )..addListener(() => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    menuController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (context) => menuController,
      child: ZoomScaffold(
        menuScreen: MenuScreen(),
        contentScreen: Layout(

            contentBuilder: (cc) => Container(
              color: Colors.grey[600],
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl: '',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _webViewController = webViewController;
                  _loadHtmlFromAssets();
                },
              ),

            )),
      ),
    );
  }
  _loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
    String fileHtmlContents = await rootBundle.loadString(filePath);
    _webViewController.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileHtmlContents,
        mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
        .toString());
  }
}
```

working demo

[image]

Comment: Thanks you Very Much For Such your Great Effort !! @chunhunghan . And something strange happening in my ide some time flutter gets works just by hot reload and next time it just get blank.....   by using your code... but now finally all the things working fine ! Thanks Again ! Have a Great Day !

Answer (score 0):

I think you have given your asset path wrong.

Change your asset path from

```
String filePath = '/assests/files/abc1.html';
```

To

```
String filePath = '/assets/files/abc1.html';
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing..but its just misspelled in both the location which i had done...  there is some other issue i think, Thanks anyway